# importing from github to gitlab

Tags: git, github, import, gitlab

I have recently moved my project from github to gitlab using the gitlab import tool which worked fine, but I am having issues to switch from github to gitlab of the local project in git bash. Creating a merge request on gitlab never shows up in git bash, and the .git setup is still connected to github. How can I move my local clone of the imported project to gitlab as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With git, you can add,remove, or modify the remote repositories you want connected to your repository.

If you will only be using the new gitlab repository, you can change the remote URL with:

```
git remote set-url origin <gitlab url> #I'm assuming you are using "origin" as the name of your remote
```

If you want both the new and old repos as remotes, add a new one with:

```
git remote add gitlab <gitlab url>
```

If you will have two (or more) remotes, you can specify which remote to use when you pull or fetch:

```
git fetch origin
git pull gitlab master
```